# Why do I have better RMSE when I don't scale the target?

Tags: neural-networks, pytorch

I use PyTorch for training a simple neural net for a regression task on a dataset with 12 numerical features + target (target is the 13th column) + 2 categorical features

Before training, I execute

```
# numeric_columns = numeric_columns[:-1]
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(df_train[numeric_columns]])
```

Also, in my custom `torch.util.data.Dataset` I scale the data using my `scaler` object.
After each epoch, I evaluate the RMSE("reversed scaled" prediction, non-scaled target), like the following:

```
y_pred = (y_pred * self.scaler.scale_[13]) + self.scaler.mean_[13] 
loss += self.criterion(y_pred , y_true).item()
```

RMSE if I don't scale the target (the first comment would be uncommented and the y_pred row would be commented) is around 0.95 (I tried multiple hyperparameters)
RMSE if I scale the target is 1.7

The target has mean 3.3 and standard deviation of 2.

What am I doing wrong? I thought scaling the target is a must when dealing with neural networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The score should be better with scaling, or not worse at least.
Check the indexing. The 13th column has the index 12, because index is zero-based. Also, if you want to leave out the 2 last categorical columns it should be `columns[:-2]`

Comment: Good catch and thanks! I used the proper mean and standard deviation and I got much closer RMSE scores